# Why does the "I've got what I need" button sometimes not work in import.io?

Tags: import.io

I am using import.io and trying to create a crawler based on this page:
http://www.flashscore.com/match/IeHoEHvJ/#match-statistics;0

After selecting single rows (one row per page), and adding some columns and training them, I want to click on the button "I've got what I need!" in order to proceed and train another similar page. But it is not possible to click on the button, it is as if the program is waiting for me to train more even though it is not necessary (I have successfully completed this procedure on other website, but for some reason this page does not work).

Any idea why this does not work?

Please see the following screenshot of import.io when I am trying to click the button without success:
http://puu.sh/j5Vlm/fcc322549a.png

UPDATE: Got a reply from the import.io facebook group. Building a Crawler might not work due to robots.txt. But building an Extractor seems to work, only have to find an easy way to collect all the links to use in the extractor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the website you're trying to scrape is probably protected by a robots.txt file so as the Facebook group told you I suggest you to try with Extractor.

The solution is a bit tricky but it should work.

1. Create an Extractor to grab the data you need from [the page you want data from](http://www.flashscore.com/match/IeHoEHvJ/#match-statistics;0). I did it and it worked.
2. Create an Extractor to get the links: (Mine is here: 5ef25069-f0cc-4ac7-9184-b2a035277403) for [this page](http://www.flashscore.com/tennis/wta-singles/wimbledon/results/)
3. Then download the dataset as CSV, open it with a spreadsheet processor and add this string of text at the end of the link: `#match-statistics;0`
4. Finally copy the list of links and go back to import.io. Choose the feature Bulk Extract on the first API and paste the list of URLs.

It should work ;)

Comment: Good answer.  I'm curious, what is the id `5ef25069-f0cc-4ac7-9184-b2a035277403` for?  How is it used?

Comment: It's the id of my extractor, you can see it at the end of the url

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I tried to use the extractor with [this URL](https://api.import.io/store/data/5ef25069-f0cc-4ac7-9184-b2a035277403/_query?input/webpage/url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flashscore.com%2Ftennis%2Fwta-singles%2Fwimbledon%2Fresults%2F).  It uses your extractor ID and the flashscore url you mentioned, but it doesn't seem to work.  Can you help?